# Bokeh Circle radius does not accept float

Tags: python, python-3.x, bokeh

I want to plot Circle markers with a specific radius.
Plotting these Circle markers with an integer works fine.

```
cavity_glyph = Circle(
            x='x_coordinate',
            y='y_coordinate',
            radius=1.,
            radius_dimension='max',
            radius_units='data',
            line_color='cavity_color'
        )
```

However, when I enter a float for the radius, nothing is plotted

```
cavity_glyph = Circle(
            x='x_coordinate',
            y='y_coordinate',
            radius=0.5,
            radius_dimension='max',
            radius_units='data',
            line_color='cavity_color'
        )
```

I read through the bokeh [reference material](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/reference/models/markers/circle.html) but could not find a solution.

I expected circles with a 0.5 radius, not an empty plot

Comment: It may be a good idea to provide (a simplified version of) the rest of the script and the data. See also [How to create a MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @norok2, I found that the error was indeed at a completely different location in the script. Problem is solved. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't reproduce your error with your example. It might be useful to check your version of Bokeh, it might have been a bug that has been fixed in a more recent release (`bokeh -v`). Here is a working example tested with Bokeh 1.2.0:

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_file, show
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource
from bokeh.models.markers import Circle

output_file("line.html")

p = figure(plot_width=800, plot_height=800)

data = {'x': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 'y': [5, 6, 7, 8, 9], 'radius': [0.1, 0.3, 0.5, 0.7, 0.9]}
source = ColumnDataSource(data)

data2 = {'x': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 'y': [9, 8, 7, 6, 5], 'radius': [0.1, 0.3, 0.5, 0.7, 0.9]}
source2 = ColumnDataSource(data2)

p.circle(x='x', y='y', radius='radius', color='navy', alpha=0.5, source=source)

cavity_glyph = Circle(
            x='x',
            y='y',
            radius='radius',
            fill_color='red',
            fill_alpha=0.5,
            radius_dimension='max',
            radius_units='data'
        )

p.add_glyph(source2, cavity_glyph)

show(p)
```

[image]

Comment: The error was somewhere else in my script causing the Circle to misbehave. Thanks for your reaction.